# Deja dup crashes while restoring backup

Tags: upgrade, backup, restore, 15.04, deja-dup

I wanted to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04. So first I made a backup using deja dup. After upgrading ubuntu, when I went to restore from that backup, It starts restoring then gets to restoring a chrome cache file and then it logs me out. Earlier when I tried, it put me on a black screen with only text, the only thing I could do is restart. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Oh man, I had the same issue. I thought I was the only one. The only difference with me that I have it saved on my external disk.

Comment: Hey, try restoring withing no other apps running. Just let the restore happen and see if that works.

Comment: @shriek I also had my backup saved on an external HDD. And it originally was running with no programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by running dejadup from a live USB and restoring the backup like that. Worked perfectly